# Capture changes in 2 datasets

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to capture change between 2 datasets based on key(s): one historical and another current version of the same dataset (both datasets share same schema). For example for input tables:

```
-- Table t_hist
-------
id  col
-------
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D

-- Table t_curr
-------
id  col
-------
1   a
2   B
4   d
5   E
```

Expected result (considering `id` as comparison key):

```
-- Table t_change
----------------
id  col change
----------------
1   a   modified
2   B   same
3   C   deleted
4   d   modified
5   E   inserted
```

A naive approach that I could think of is:

```
SELECT id, col, change FROM
(
    SELECT t_curr.id, t_curr.col, 
        CASE t_curr.col = t_hist.col
        WHEN true THEN 'same'
        ELSE 'modified' 
        END as change
    FROM t_curr INNER JOIN t_hist ON t_curr.id = t_hist.id
) 
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT t_curr.id, t_curr.col, 'inserted' as change
    FROM t_curr WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t_hist)
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT t_hist.id, t_hist.col, 'deleted' as change
    FROM t_hist WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t_curr)
)
```

But this approach involves multiple table scans (3 times for each dataset). It is also possible that before querying the 2 datasets, user may need to do some transformation / filter on the datasets, say only fetch rows from both sets where `id > 2`. In that case this approach would be more in-efficient. I'm looking for an efficient way of achieving the same result. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

It is also possible that any of the dataset would have duplicates like:

```
-- Table t_curr
-------
id  col
-------
1   A
1   B
2   C

-- Table t_hist
-------
id  col
-------
1   B
2   C
2   D

-- Table t_change
----------------
id  col change
----------------
1   A   modified   -- change status is 'modified' as first row for matching key is different
1   B   inserted
2   C   same
2   D   deleted
```

In such case my query would not produce desired output. Thanks @Gordon Linoff for bringing up the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can use `full join` -- assuming `id`s are unique in each table:

```
select id,
       (case when h.id is null then 'New'
             when c.id is null then 'Deleted'
             when h.col <> c.col then 'Modified'
             else 'Same'
        end)
from t_hist h full join
     t_curr c
     using (id);
```

Note:  This does not take into account `NULL` values for the value column(s).  That logic can easily be incorporated but adds an additional complication that doesn't seem necessary based on your sample data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out uniqueness scenario for `id`. It could be the case that `id`s are duplicate. Edited my question.

Comment: @justAbit . . . It is better to ask a *new* question than to invalidate answers.

Comment: created a follow-up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61570412/capture-changes-between-2-datasets-with-duplicates