# Capture changes between 2 datasets with duplicates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is a follow-up question of [Capture changes in 2 datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61559925/capture-changes-in-2-datasets).
I need to capture change between 2 datasets based on key(s): one historical and another current version of the same dataset (both datasets share same schema). These datasets can have duplicate rows as well. In below example `id` is considered key for comparison:

```
-- Table t_curr
-------
id  col
-------
1   A
1   B
2   C
3   F

-- Table t_hist
-------
id  col
-------
1   B
2   C
2   D
4   G
-- Expected output t_change
----------------
id  col change
----------------
1   A   modified   -- change status is 'modified' as first row for id=1 is different for both tables
1   B   inserted
2   C   same
2   D   deleted
3   F   inserted
4   G   deleted
```

I'm looking for an efficient solution to get the desired output.

**EDIT**

**Explanation:** While fetching data from `t_curr` if records come in the same order as shown and *records were ranked wrt to* `id`:

1. `1/A` is first and `1/B` second records in `t_curr`
2. `1/B` is the first records in `t_hist`
3. 1st record for both datasets compared ie `1/A` in `t_curr` compared with `1/B` of `t_hist` hence `1/A` marked as `modified` in `t_change`
4. Since `1/B` present only in `t_curr` it's
   marked `inserted`

Comment: There are no date fields ?

Comment: I'm lost.  `1/B` is in both tables.  How is it "inserted"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff added explanation.

Comment: @Raj it's not mandatory to have date field.

Comment: @justAbit there should be a streamingDate added, otherwise you don't know the order, and which is the most recent one.

Comment: What have you done so far? Did you try using scripting? I think scripting fits this problem better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using `full outer join` and `row_number()`. Query:

```
with t_hist as (
select 1 as id, 'B' as col union all
select 2 as id, 'C' as col union all
select 2 as id, 'D' as col union all
select 4 as id, 'G' as col
),
t_curr as (
select 1 as id1,    'A' as col1 union all
select 1 as id1,    'B' as col1 union all
select 2 as id1,    'C' as col1 union all
select 3 as id1,    'F' as col1
)

select
  case when id1 is null then id else id1 end as id_,
  case when col1 is null then col else col1 end as col_,
  case 
    when id is null then 'inserted'
    when id1 is null then 'deleted'
    when col = col1 then 'same'
    else 'modified'
    end
  as change
from
(select t_curr.*, t_hist.* from (select *, row_number() over (partition by id1 order by id1) r1 from t_curr) t_curr 
full outer join (select *, row_number() over (partition by id) r from t_hist ) t_hist on id1 = id and r1 = r )
order by id_
```